# What is that cat trying to do?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, multi-pet-families

### Introduction:

I have a male pet cat whose name is Gulu and his mother's name is Kuchi who is a stray cat we used to feed.

We don't really keep him in all the time. He can go in and out anytime he wants.

So nearly two months ago it seemed that Gulu was trying to find female cats in heat.

I don't think he found one because one month ago I was seeing him always following his mother. It seemed that he was trying to make a relationship with his mother, which was problematic, so we tried to stop him. But the interest died out quickly.

But things got weird.

### My question:

So what really got weird? After Gulu's interest fading away, it seemed that Kuchi started to show interest in him.

Now what kind of interest is she showing, I am not sure. Because many times she meowed in a sort of deep tone which kinda sounds like howling which seemed to make Gulu wanting to go to her (I think that is how cats call each other).

But the weird thing is that whenever Gulu reaches her or she somehow reaches Gulu, she aggressively starts to lick and slowly goes to the weak spots of him such as belly or neck and bites him. Being uncomfortable by that Gulu goes and sits afar from her, but then she goes and starts to bite him everywhere, not really being a fighter, Gulu just pushes her away but she starts to bite him more aggressively and then starts to attack him. So Gulu finally starts to attack her. And a fight starts out which only stopped by either Gulu winning or by our intervention.

This is weird. What the heck does she want from Gulu? Can someone please give some explanations?

#### Gulu:

[image]

#### Kuchi:

[image]

Comment: This is not answering your question, but please get at least one of your cats spayed! Inbreeding is the last thing you want.

Comment: In nature the mothers chase away their sons to avoid inbreeding for themself and the daughters. Maybe the mum is not calling her son, but a male in general. And when the son comes to her, she want to chase him away. This would follow some general rules to avoid inbreeding in nature. And you could be sure, he found a female. As far as I know, they will not build pairs for more time than to mate... And so the son is not coming back to his mother, but back to his food-delivery-service ;)

Comment: @Allerleirauh. I actually thought that but the more I observe the more it seems that she wants Gulu because whenever Gulu comes in our home, she starts to howl until Gulu gets out and goes to her and starts playing. So it seemed at first that maybe they are just being friends but the playing turns into and aggressive fight because of Kuchi's behaviour towards Gulu.

Comment: Are there other male cats around or allowed in your home? It could be, that the female reacts to the near smell of a male, noticing later, that it is her son. Females react to near males, maybe with howling

Comment: No, we don't allow other male cats be in our home. But some other male cats do sometimes come near our home or stay with her.

Comment: @Allerleirauh. I don't think so. Because if that was the case then why would she follow him and when Gulu goes near her, why would she lick him at first instead of attacking.